# Why is the height of my inline-block element smaller than the image inside of it?

Tags: css

`.left-icons` is `inline-block` and has a `height` of `21px`:

[image]

Note that the `height` of the image inside of it is `38px`:

[image]

CSS Tricks [says](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/height/):

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly, and
>   the element is not absolutely positioned, the value of its height
>   computes to auto (it will be as tall as the content inside it is, or
>   zero if there is no content).

The height of the containing block isn't being explicitly specified. So why is my outer element smaller than the image inside of it?

---

**HTML**

```
<div class='tango-directive-template'>

<div class='tango level-{{ level }}'>
  <span class='left-icons'>
    <img
      ng-show='tango.children.length > 0'
      src='/assets/images/show-arrow.png'>
    <span class='author'>A</span>
  </span>
  <textarea
    ng-focus='focus = true;'
    ng-blur='focus = false;'
    rows='1'>{{ tango.text }}</textarea>
  <p class='menu' ng-show='focus'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-indent-left'></span>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-indent-right'></span>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down'></span>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'></span.
  </p>
</div>

<tango
  ng-repeat='subtango in tango.children'
  tango='subtango'
  level='{{ +level + 1 }}'>
</tango>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tango-directive-template {
  .tango {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    .left-icons {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: right;
      width: 67px;
      img, .author {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 15px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        height: 100%;
      }
      img {
        height: 20px;
      }
      .author {
        border: 1px solid gray;
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    }
    textarea {
      font-size: 18px;
      width: 700px;
      line-height: 135%;
      padding: 8px 16px;
      resize: none;
      border: 1px solid white;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    textarea:focus {
      outline: none;
      border: 1px solid gray;
      overflow: auto; // only have scroll bar when focused
    }
    .menu {
      width: 750px;
      span {
        float: right;
        margin-left: 15px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    }
  }
  @for $i from 0 through 10 {
    .level-#{$i} {
      position: relative;
      left: #{$i*65}px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Here it works: http://jsfiddle.net/6qu5h7L2/. Can you post yours on JSFIDDLE, please?

Comment: Hi Adam, it's hard to tell why without seeing the style rules applied to each element. Your CSS-Tricks reference is right. Something in the styles may be overriding the default behavior. Post the code if possible.

Comment: I updated the question with my full code. As for JSFiddle, I'm not really sure what I could extract out without losing important information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should try a clearfix method.

Look here: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: Not on `inline-block`. :-/

Comment: Why not on `inline-block`?

Comment: Look there, maybe that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best

Answer (score 0):

Use an inline block.

```
span.left-icons{
  display: inline-block;
}
```